# How do I offset centered text (without fancy CSS, DHTML, etc.)?

Tags: html

Quick, hopefully easy question.  Google is failing me.  I don't want my text exactly centered.  I want it maybe 7 characters (blank spaces) over. What do I add to this to do that?  <.center>This is centered<./center>

Adding blanks in front of the "T" does nothing.

(I added the dots in the code above because I can't get <.code> blocks/spans to let me put the html code here.)

(Nothing fancy - no CSS, DHTML, XHTML - just plain old HTML.)

Thanks.

Comment: You can edit your post and add <pre><code> code here </code></pre> around your HTML code so MarkDown doesn't strip it from the post.

Comment: You can use back ticks \` to format the code like this `<center>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `&nbsp;` non-breaking space to nudge it over. Insert seven of these and it will move over seven spaces.